Is there an error within this definition of existential generalization?
The author defines existential generalization as follows:

Consider the formula $\phi(t) := t \neq x$. Since $t$ is free for $x$ in $\phi$ (indeed, $\phi$ is $\neg(t = x)$ with $t = x$ being atomic), according to the lemma, we would have $\exists x \phi(x)$, which translates to $\exists x (x \neq x)$, that shall evaluate to true. However, this formula is false.
Am I missing something in this reasoning?

@MauroALLEGRANZA, sorry, I must be confused
Other definitions of existential introduction require $x$ not to appear free if $\phi(t)$, which makes sense to me. Is the given an equivalent requirement?

You can validly derive a contradiction from another contradiction … and within the context of this proof system, $t \neq x$ effectively represents a contradiction.

See this post for the correct reading of $(\exists \text I)$ rule: we start with a formula $φ(x)$ with a free occurrence of $x$ and we replace that occurrence with a term $t$.
Thus, from $φ[x/t]$ we can derive $∃xφ$.
Considering your case, we have as $φ$ the formula $(x≠t)$ and thus the result of the substituion $φ[x/t]$ will be: $(t≠t)$.
Applying $(\exists \text I)$ to it we get $\exists x (x \ne x)$.
